# I have not yet invested into a TFSA - how much can I invest in 2011?

Tags: canada, investing, savings, tfsa

I have not yet created a TFSA, nor invested anything in it. I am looking to put some money in in 2011, what will my cap be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the gory details are available [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/tfsa-celi/cntrbtn-eng.html).

More specifically your personal limit will be listed on you last tax assessment notice, that you would have received last April-ish when you filed last year's taxes.

As a first approximation, **your situation may differ**, if you have never contributed anything, your limit is likely $15,000 (as the program has been running three years as of 2011).

Comment: That's my personal limit for 2010, correct? Once I file my 2011 taxes I'll find out my new personal limit?

Comment: The (simplistic) math is basically $5,000 per year so far, so 2009 and 2010 give you $10k, and another $5k this year.

Comment: Additional info:  **Contribution room for TFSAs does not start until age 18.**  So, only individuals who were 18 or older in 2009 (when TFSAs started) would have a full $15,000 contribution room available today.